# Customised regex in ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

I want to check if a string states Above 60. **Example:**
`'>60'`, `'> 60'`, `'above60'`, `'above 60'`, `'Above60'`, `'Above 60'`, OR more than 1 space in between (> and 60), (above and 60), (Above and 60).

How can I write a regex to validate a string that starts with either (>, above or Above) then any number of spaces and ends with 60?

Comment: What about `more than 60` or `60+`?

Comment: Nope! according to my use case, only need the one I stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I write a regex to validate a string that starts with either (>, above or Above) then any number of spaces and ends with 60?

It's very straight forward:

- a string that starts with either `>`, `above` or `Above`

  ```
  /^(>|above|Above)/
  ```
- then any number of spaces

  ```
  /^(>|above|Above)\s*/
  ```
- and ends with 60

  ```
  /^(>|above|Above)\s*60$/
  ```

Note that in Ruby, `^` and `$` match beginning and end of a line, not string. You might want to change that to `\A` and `\z` respectively. And instead of specifying both cases explicitly (`above` / `Above`), you could append an `i` to make the regexp case-insensitive, i.e. `/^(>|above)\s*60$/i`.

As always, there's more than one way to get the desired result. I can recommend Rubular for fiddling with regular expressions: https://rubular.com/r/EEHBSOB3PK2Djk

Comment: Thank-you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
r = /\A(?:>|[aA]bove) *60\z/
```

```
['>60', '> 60', 'above60', 'above    60', 'Above60', 'Above 60'].all? do |s|
  s.match?(r)
end
  #=> true

[' >60', '> 600', ' above60', 'above    600', 'Above60 '].any? do |s|
  s.match?(r)
end
  #=> false
```

We can write the regular expression in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting.

```
/
\A       # match beginning of string
(?:      # begin a non-capture group
  >      # match '>'
  |      # or
  [aA]   # match 'a' or 'A'
  bove   # match 'bove'
)        # end non-capture group
[ ]*     # match 0+ spaces
60       # match '60'
\z       # match end of string
/x       # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

Notice that in the above I placed the space in a character class (`[ ]`). Alternatively I could have escaped the space, used `[[:space:]]` or one of a few other options. Without protecting the space in one of these ways it would be stripped out (when using free-spacing mode) before the regex is parsed.

When spaces are to be reflected in a regex I use space characters rather than whitespace characters (`\s`), mainly because the latter also match end-of-line terminators (`\n` and possibly `\r`) which can result in problems.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
/(>|above|more than){0,1} *60\+*/i
```

- The `i` at the end of the regex is for case insensitivity.
- If you need additional prefixes, just add it after `more than` separated by a pipe `|`

Comment: `aBOVE` is OK ?

Comment: verified it on rubular